# How to get an exact result number of output?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

i want to ask on how do i get an exact number of output result that i want? the code that i used don't exactly output 500, it's either <500 or >500. this is the code that i use

```
import random

Website = open("dictionaries/Website.txt", 'w', encoding="utf-8")
delimiters = ['', '-', '.']
suffix = ['co.id', 'info', 'id', 'com', 'odoo', 'xyz', 'de', 'fans', 'blog', 'io', 'site', 'online', 'one']

web = ['auth', 'access', 'account', 'admin', 'agree', 'blue', 'business', 'cdn', 'confirm', 'confirmation', 'enroll']
missed = ['minecraft', 'm1necraft', 'min3craft', 'm1necr4ft', 'min3cr4ft']

output = []

for i in range(500):
    for subdomain_count in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
        pl = random.choice(missed)
        data = [pl] + random.sample(web, k=subdomain_count)
        random.shuffle(data)
        delims = (random.choices(delimiters, k=subdomain_count) +
            ['.' + random.choice(suffix)])
        address = ''.join([a+b for a, b in zip(data, delims)])
        weburl = 'http://' + address
        Website.write(weburl+'\n')

with open("dictionaries/Website.txt") as f:
    WebPhishing = [line.rstrip() for line in f]

print(len(WebPhishing))
```

In this code example i put the range 1 - 4, which supposed to be 500 * 4, the output from that range does not print out the exact number that i want, it would sometimes be >2000 or <2000.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> how do i get an exact number of output result that i want?

Your nested loops produce 500 * 4 == 2000 results.

If you want a different number of results, adjust the loop bounds.

Comment: for that one yes, if i have 4 types of subdomain count i want it to be 500 * n, but the output doesn't exacly output the total 2000, it would sometimes output >2000 or <2000 @J_H